# Row not adding in grid control devExpress

Tags: c#

am adding row in grid control through column view. But it is not working. Even though I am providing correct information.

```
private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter;
    readStudent();
    ColumnView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as ColumnView;

    foreach (PAT p in pt_list)
    {
        String s1 = p.name;

        view.AddNewRow(); //Problem here:not adding row
        int count = view.RowCount-1;
        view.SetRowCellValue(view.GetRowHandle(count), "PAT Name", s1);

        foreach(Student1 student in st_lst)
        {
            counter = 1;
            foreach (Allocate al in al_list) {
            if (p.ID == al.AID && student.UOB == al.AUOB)
            {

                String s = student.name;
                view.SetRowCellValue(view.GetRowHandle(count), "Student "+ counter, s);

                counter++;
            }          
        }

    }
    gridControl1.DataSource = view;
}
```

can anybody help me with that

Comment: Winforms or WPF?? Since it's a gridControl I need to know which type it is..

Comment: actually i am using gridcontrol in user control which is placed in winform.

Comment: Could you add the code you use in the function view.AddNewRow();??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is still active but you cannot use the `GridView` as `gridControl1.DataSource`. This has to be a data-construct and not a sub-part of the GridControl itself. So use a list of objects or a DataTable as dataSource and add your new student there.

See [the DevExpress help](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387) on how to bind a list of objects.